# Function on a vector independent on the element memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am implementing a function operating on a vector of certain objects, let's say for simplicity it computes a sum.

The logic of the function is independent on whether it is a vector of objects, raw pointers to objects or unique/weak/shared pointers.

How can I accomplish it without repeating the code and with smallest overhead for the user?

---

EDIT:

The solution works for different pointers, but not for objects. Well, maybe there is not way around it except using pointers everywhere and force the user to create vector of pointers if he wants to use the function. At least is  easier than the other way around.

I wanted to keep my object type if possible somehow, because I was happy with it.  Now instead of vector of Players, Widgets, Matrices or whatever meaningful things I am forced to use T. In that case I would love to have something like  `template <class T extends MyLovelyClass>`, but that's not C++...

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class A{
public:
    int get(){return 1;}
};

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
int sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    T result = {};
    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        result += (*it)->get();
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<A> v(10);
    std::vector<A*> w(10);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> u(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++){
        w[i] = new A();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++){
        u[i] = std::make_shared<A>();
    }

    //sum<int>(v.begin(), v.end()); //doesn't work

    sum<int>(w.begin(), w.end());
    sum<int>(u.begin(), u.end());
}
```

Comment: Do like the standard library does and take a begin and end iterator and process the range `[begin, end)`.

Comment: Wrap the algorithm into a template function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you expand on that? I don't see how you can use same template for a pointer and object. In the template function I either need T->getSomething() or T.getSomething(), right?

Comment: You could make a standalone accessor, and overload for pointers & references.  `auto getSomething(T& t) { return t.getSomething(); }` and `auto getSomething(T* t) { return t->getSomething(); }`.

Comment: _@Utka_ Well, you'll need to serve some interface to iterate within a certain range as @Nathan mentioned, no?

Comment: @JustinTime  thanks, this is more in the direction I wanted to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your algorithm using template function. Here is the sample of template function is given.

```
template<typename T>
return_type functionName(vector<T> var) {
    // You can do this multiple way, First approach
    T sum = T();
    for(const auto& it: var) {
        sum += it;
    }
    // 2nd Approach
    for(int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++) {
        sum += var[i];
    }
}
```

For more details on template and it's use please read [An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 1](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/257589/an-idiots-guide-to-cplusplus-templates-part-1) and [An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 2](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/268849/an-idiots-guide-to-cplusplus-templates-part)

Comment: It's probably better to pass the vector by reference than by value.

Comment: That's specialized for `std::vector`. I doubt that was intended in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it templates my type, which I prefer to keep somehow if possible, but doesn't work for object vs. pointer which is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The logic of the function is independent on whether it is a vector of objects, raw pointers to objects or unique/weak/shared pointers.

The idiomatic approach is to wrap such algorithm into a template function, that takes iterator template parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename Iterator>
T sum(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    T result = {};
    for(auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        result += *it;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here are several ways to use it

```
std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int sum1 = sum<int>(v.begin(),v.end());

std::array<int, 5> a { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int sum2 = sum<int>(a.begin(),a.end());

int ra[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int sum3 = sum<int>(std::begin(ra),std::end(ra));

int* da = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int sum4 = sum<int>(da,da+5);
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e01e38960511d77).

Comment: Thanks, this works for different type of pointers, but not for pointer vs object. Also, I rather wanted to keep my object type if possible, since template kind of forces me to give it up for a generic type.

Comment: I edited my answer to include part of your code, do you mind taking a look?